# Poincaré inequality in the space $H_{r}^{2}$

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I know that the below Poincare's inequality is valid in the space $$H_{E}^{2}=\left \{ y\in H^{2}(0,1)\mid y(0)=y_{x}(0)=0 \right \}$$
Let $w(x, t)$, $x ∈ (0, 1)$, $t ∈ (0, ∞)$ satisfies the boundary condition $w(0, t)=0$. Then we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left | w(x,t) \right |^{2}dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left | w_{x}(x,t) \right |^{2}dx$$
$$\left | w(1,t) \right |^{2} \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left | w_{x}(x,t) \right |^{2}dx$$

where the symbole $y_{x}$ denotes the derivative of $y$ with respect to x.

My question is : is this lemma still valid in the space
$$H_{r}^{2}=\left \{ y\in H^{2}(0,L)\mid y(L)=y_{x}(L)=0 \right \}$$
by changing the boundary coundation from $0$ to $L\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, just do the change of variable $y = L (1-x)$. You will just get a different constant.